# Grant Active Directory Group Access To SQL Server Express Database

Tags: active-directory, sql-server-express

As you can guess from the title I am attempting to assign an entire Active Directory group access to a database on SQL Server Express (via the command line with the SQLCMD.exe application).

I've previously posted a similiar question but I, nor the people who responded to me have been able to find the solution. (Link: [Using sp_grantlogin And sp_addsrvrolemember To Add An Active Directory Group To SQL Server Users Using SQLCMD.EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362034/using-sp-grantlogin-and-sp-addsrvrolemember-to-add-an-active-directory-group-to)).

So far I have only been able to grant access to individual members of the Active Directory group by specifying the domain name followed by their username, i.e. 'DomainName\UserName'.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out - I'm a total novice with SQL Server Express.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it's a two step process.

**Step 1:** create a server **login** for the AD group:

```
CREATE LOGIN [YOURDOMAIN\SomeGroupName] FROM WINDOWS;
```

**Step 2:** once you have the server login, go to the database in question and create a user based on that login:

```
USE YourDatabaseNameHere
CREATE LOGIN [YOURDOMAIN\SomeGroupName] FROM WINDOWS;
```

Comment: Thanks fo your response @marc_s. I presently do not have permissions to execute the first command. Have you any idea what the default admin username and passwords are for SQL Server Express?

Comment: @slickboy: nope, sorry - there's no default (like with some other RDBMS) - you need to ask your DBA ...

Comment: Thanks @marc_s. Out of curiority when I execute the following command am I logging into SQL Server Express using my own current Windows Account Credential? "SERVERPATH\SQLCMD -S SERVER_NAME\SERVER_INSTANCE".

Comment: @slickboy: yes - unless you explicitly specify another account (`-u someusername -p password`), then your current Windows credentials will be used

Comment: Thats great @marc_s...thanks for your help! I've been stuck on this for ages!